# WP7- Confused about network communication, cross thread access, and continuation passing

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I'm porting a WPF app to WP7, and in the process I've had to refactor all the code that touches the network.  The old code used the synchronous methods of the WebRequest object in background threads, but these methods no longer exist in WP7.

The result has been bewildering, and makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong.  I've had to litter my views with thread dispatching code - the only alternative to this that I see is to supply the dispatcher to the lower tiers of the app, which would break platform-independence and muddy the boundary with the UI.  I've lost the ability to make chained calls over the network from loops, and instead have callbacks invoking themselves.  I've lost try/catch error handling and instead have OnSuccess and OnError callbacks everywhere.  I'm now always unintentionally running code in background threads that are invoked by callbacks.  I fondly remember the days when I was able to return values from methods.

I know continuation-passsing-style is supposed to be great, but I think all of the above has made the code more brittle and less readable, and has made threading issues more complex than they need to be.

Apologies if this question is vague, I'd just like to know if I'm missing some big picture here.

Comment: Was there a question here?  I must have missed it.  Is the Async CTP compatible with Silverlight and WP7?  It might be able to help you out on making your methods easier on the eyes.

Comment: WPF to WP7 is a pretty serious jump.  You would probably encounter very similar problems moving from WPF to Silverlight (which, that's pretty much what is going on, right?).  For what it's worth, you're not crazy, and you're looking at fundamentally different architectures on the platforms.  Bending existing code to fit a different architecture will make your code more brittle and less readable, so be careful with that.

Comment: Jeff - I guess my question is how to overcome the limitations I mentioned.  Or, at the very least, I'd like to understand what the point is, of being forced to code in this style.  

The Async CTP contains future c# 5.0 features, which I think will help me out quite a bit, but I have to keep my code mono compatible, so I can't use those features until then.

And thanks for the reassurance Bryan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this seem to behave like buses.  You don't see any for ages then two come along almost at the same time.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537918/silverlight-httpwebrequest-syncronous-call/5538448#5538448) to a more concrete version of this question asked earlier today.

I have to I agree with you, continuation passing is tricky.  A really useful technique is to borrow the C# `yield return` construct to create a machine that is able to maintain state between asynchronous operations.  For a really good explanation see this [blog](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/03/sequential-asynchronous-workflows-in.html) by Jeremy Likness.

Personally I prefer a "less is more" approach so the [AsyncOperationService](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/09/12/simple-asynchronous-operation-runner-ndash-part-1.aspx) is a very small chunk of code.  You'll note that it has a single callback for both success and failure and there no interfaces to implement just a moderate delegate `Action<Action<Exception>>` which is typed as `AsyncOperation` to make it more convenient.

The basic steps to coding against this are:-

- Code as if synchronous execution were possible
- Create methods that return an `AsyncOperation` fpr only the smallest part that has to be asynchronous.  Usually some `WebRequest` or WCF call but note just enough to get past the async bit, see me other answer for a good example.
- Convert the synchronous "psuedo-code" to `yeild` these AsyncOperations and change the calling code to "Run" the resulting enumerable.

The final code looks quite similar to the synchronous code you might be more familar with.

As to accidentally running things on a background thread, that last answer included this useful AsyncOperation:-

```
public static AsyncOperation SwitchToUIThread()
{
    return (completed => Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => completed(null)));
}
```

You can use that as the final `yield` in the run to ensure that code executing in the `completed` callback is executing on the UI thread.  Its also useful to "flip" what is apparently synchronous code to be running on the UI thread when necessary.

Comment: It'll take me a while to fully wrap my head around this, but its ingenious and really seems like the way to go.  Never would have thought of it myself in a million years, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of Silverlight, which requires asynchronous network access (WCF proxy calls, WebClient, WebRequest, etc.). All synchronous network-reliant method calls have been removed from the framework.

To be crass: welcome to asynchronous programming. The only thing you did wrong was not making the calls asynchronous in the first place :)

I'm not 100% clear on the exact reasons MS removed the sync calls from web-dependent objects in Silverlight, but the explanations I hear always center on one or two reasons in some combination:

- Browsers are architected on asynchronous network calls. Introducing synchronous calls would cause bad behavior/broken apps/crashes/etc.
- If they gave everyone the "easy out" of making synchronous calls, the world would be littered with Silverlight apps that always froze while doing anything on the network, making Silverlight as a platform look bad.

That said - WCF proxies in Silverlight have the behavior that they always perform their callback on the calling thread. This is most often the UI thread, meaning you don't have to do any dispatching. I do not know if WebClient/WebRequest in Silverlight share this behavior.

As for the dispatcher, you could look into using a SynchronizationContext instead. The MVVM reference implementation in the MS Patterns and Practices Prism guidance does this - in the repository (data access class that actually makes calls out to an abstracted external service), they have a SynchronizationContext member that is initialized to System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current. This is the UI thread, if the constructor is called on the UI thread (it should be). All results from the service calls are then handled with mySynchronizationContext.Post.

Comment: As for the second excuse, if this is really how MS thinks its despicable.  Its not their job to police devs.  I would never use a sync call on the UI thread, but it should be up to me how I achieve asynchronous behavior, as opposed to being force into The One Way.  I have monotouch code that accomplishes async behavior just fine without using the async calls.

As for the synchcontext - thanks for the tip, it really did the trick!

Comment: @tempy:  To be fair if MS had provided a Synchronous only API then your hands would be "forced into One Way".  In reality by having an asynchronous interface MS merely forces you to actually make a __choice__ to be synchronous.  There is nothing stopping you blocking on the WaitHandle from a Begin.  However there is more to it than asychronicity.  There is a danger with synchronous coding to accidently tie up a pool thread forever.  Do that too often and your app will brick.  Ultimately MS are attempting to avoid Silverlight getting a bad rep when apps are written poorly.

Comment: That's not true about the WaitHandle - it doesn't work in silverlight/WP7, and the WP7 forums have plenty of people attempting it and scratching their heads over the "interesting" results.  So there is only one "choice" to be made.